# Trying to use "grid" and "place" in one frame after using "pack" in another frame but widgets are not visible

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on an invoice generator in python tkinter for my coursework. I am quite new to programming and I have created a basic login page so when the login button is pressed (haven't setup restraints yet)  the GUI moves to the next 'screen.' I am using frames to do this. However, on the next 'page' I can only pack() widgets, if I try and place them or use a grid they simply don't appear and I get an empty GUI window. 
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def go_to_login():
    f1.pack()
    f2.pack_forget()

def go_to_first():
    f1.pack_forget()
    f2.pack()

root.geometry('1280x800')
root.title('Invoice')

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
label_US = tk.Label(f1, text='Username')
label_US.pack()
label_PW = tk.Label(f1, text='Password')
label_PW.pack()

entry_US = tk.Entry(f1)
entry_US.pack()
entry_PW = tk.Entry(f1, show='*')
entry_PW.pack()

checkbox_LI = tk.Checkbutton(f1, text='Keep me logged in')
checkbox_LI.pack()

but_LI = tk.Button(f1, text='login', command=go_to_first)
but_LI.pack()

but_QT = tk.Button(f1, text='Quit', command=quit)
but_QT.pack()

f2 = tk.Frame(root)
but_LO = tk.Button(f2, text='Logout', command=go_to_login)
but_LO.pack()  # try to change pack here

but_HP = tk.Button(f2, text='Help')
but_HP.pack()  # try to change pack here

but_NX1 = tk.Button(f2, text='Next', command=quit)
but_NX1.pack()  # try to change pack here

f1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

What I basically want is to be able to `place` or use `grid` to set the locations of my widgets also on the second frame, but unless I use `pack` I get an empty GUI screen. What have I done wrong or how can I place the widgets instead to packing them?

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do things and I have no experience using classes etc but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: For me, it works if I change `pack` to `grid`. You're probably not using `grid` and `place` as you think you're using. Check the documentation for those geometry managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you specify the `row` and `column` when using `.grid()`, the code works fine for both 'screens'. I can think of two possible reasons why you're code wasn't working

1) If you try and use `.pack` and `.grid` for two labels in the same frame, you will get an error

2) There may be something else in your code causing your error, if so, add it to your question

Anyway, **here's the code that worked for me:**

```
f2 = tk.Frame(root)
but_LO = tk.Button(f2, text='Logout', command=go_to_login)
but_LO.grid(row = 0, column = 0)  # specify row and column

but_HP = tk.Button(f2, text='Help')
but_HP.grid(row = 1, column = 0)  

but_NX1 = tk.Button(f2, text='Next', command=quit)
but_NX1.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
```